# Is it possible to run a *completely* client-side, HTML5-based app using local storage?

Tags: html, canvas, local, offline

Is it possible to run a completely HTML5-based app, using the `<canvas>` element, on local resources only? i.e. without the need to connect to a remote server to load bitmap images, objects, media, etc' but instead pull them out of local storage?

Comment: How would you get the resources and code *into* local storage?

Answer (score 2):

In a word.  Yes.  But not out of local storage, if you mean the local storage name value pair alternative to session storage that is available in HTML5.

If you mean save them locally in a file structure and use them, then yes.

You need to use a manifest file to specify the required artifacts, as outlined by [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/offline.html).

Here's a great resource [http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/offline.html](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to give to the user the resources at the beginning, on a way or the other...

If you want an app to rely just on the local data, I would suggest a "packaged app" for Chrome, so the user downloads it once and the use it locally.

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/apps.html

Otherwise with the HTML5 "manifest" you can ask the app to keep the once downloaded file available even when offline.